# PHP Is echoing snippets slower than echoing all at once?

Tags: php, performance, echo

I have a practical question about page load time:

Suppose I want the following output:

```
<a class="class-a" href="www.google.com"></a>
```

Is it faster (with respect to load time and efficiency) to do:

```
<a class="<?php echo $class_a; ?>" href="<?php echo $url; ?>"></a>
```

or

```
echo "<a class='$class_a' href='$url'></a>";
```

This is a microcosm of a bigger issue-- if I'm using echo multiple times on the page is it better to try to condense HTML output into one variable and echo it in one go??

Thanks!

Comment: A double quoted string needs to be interpreted by PHP, while the HTML-markup (except for the replacements) must not be interpreted. If you're heavily using double-quoted strings, this might be slower, but probably not a lot. Just a hint: If you're using PHP within a "template" (i.e. a lot of HTML markup, and only a few replacements) there is a nice shortcut: <a class="<?=$class_a?>" href="<?=$url?>"></a>

Comment: Please ask practical, not theoretical questions here. See as well the FAQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those two really make no difference. One or two echo doesn't matter. 1000 echo doesn't matter. Really when you look at the grand scale of things, echos do not matter. I can run 5million echos per second on my laptop in a tight loop. Doing one SQL query that takes 1ms or 2ms to run means you get a difference of 5000 echo calls more or less. That's how irrelevant it is.

What you want to do is look at your code with a profiler and find the bottlenecks if you have performance problems, but don't worry about how many echos you do. And by the way you probably should use something like [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) to print HTML using templates instead of raw PHP like in your example, at least this gives you automatic HTML entities escaping, which protects you against XSS for example.

Answer (score 1):

in terms of performance the second is faster because printing to an output is expensive operation. BUT you should be careful to not sacrifice an esay to read code for fast executed code.

Comment: I don't think that the first one is not an easy code. IMHO it's quite the opposite. The first one directly tells you: There is PHP printing variables inside of a string. Most syntax highlighters won't even show you that `$class_a` and `$url` are variables in the second one. Maybe this would be even better in terms of performance and readability: `echo '<a class="' . $class_a . '" href="' . $url . '"></a>';`

Comment: @YMMD: agreed, actually i never said the second was more readable, (sorry if i implied that) it was just a point because people tend to look for performance in the wrong places, your solution its also a good one btw.

Answer (score 1):

I have performed a test similar to what you are asking before.

Out of the two examples you posted I found that the first one is marginally slower compared to the second.

If you store the output into a buffer before hand you will use more memory and it is again marginally slower than the slowest of the two examples you gave.

As other people have pointed out it is completely irrelevant and I would put ease of maintainability and readability above any kind of speed optimisations you think you might get.

Answer (score 0):

Completely pointless micro-optimization. Whether there's a difference at all depends on what PHP runtime exactly you use, but it's going to be totally irrelevant compared with DB access of any kind, the server configuration, and bytecode caching.

This is not the kind of thing you should worry about even a second, *especially* if performance is important.

Comment: whar if I'm talking about comparing the two inside of a loop that iterates 1000 times?

Comment: @j-man86: Run a benchmark if you want to be certain, but I'm willing to bet you 2:1 that it still won't matter.